# WP7 validation of viewmodel or model data

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm

Are there any frameworks or built in mechanisms to perform validation on properties of either model classes or view model classes in WP7?
Ideally I don't want to setup NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True and BindingValidationError on every single property in the view and perform switches in the code behind for the property name.Also I would prefer to have the validation logic in either the VM class or the Model class and not the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

> Also I would prefer to have the validation logic in either the VM class

`IDataErrorInfo` is also applied to the view-model. If you're exposing data models directly to the view, you're doing it wrong in the first place.

There's probably some frameworks, if you bother looking for them, but there's nothing extra build-in, than the validation methods you already know (IDataErrorInfo).

Comment: I'm exposing my models to the VM and the VM in turn exposes the properties the view needs  by having the property getters call into the model so no I'm not exposing the model directly. Currently my VM is implementing IDataErrorInfo. I already looked at frameworks such as MVVM light etc. to check if validation has been implemented but did nto find any and hence this question has been posted here.I have "BindingValidationError" for every input control on my page pointing to corresponding handler method but this seems repetitve and unmaintanable in the long run.